# Choosing asynchronous microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I am working on a project that reads the moisture level of the soil, stores it (datalogger) and, depending on certain conditions, it opens a valve to water the soil. I am designing the PCB for the system, and I'm struggling to choose the microcontroller.

It works with capacitive sensors (analog), but I want the microcontroller to read data from all the sensors (10 sensors) simultaneously (meaning async) instead of doing them in order. I first tested this system with an AtMega328-P (with 4 sensors), then an AtMega2560 (with 10 sensors), and now I want to see if this can be improved using a PIC or other microcontroller.

In the future I want to use LoRa, so that the sensors can communicate with the central using a signal instead of wires, and that will require a lot of resources as well.

I do not want to use a Raspberry Pi or expensive CPUs as this has to be "low cost".

Comment: That's not what asynchronous means. Asynchronous computing is an active area of research and definitely not something you should be messing with if you don't understand what you're doing. It's not the microcontroller that matters here, it's the ADC(s).

Comment: "*It works with capacitive sensors (analog), but I want the microcontroller to read data from all the sensors (10 sensors) simultaneously (meaning async) instead of doing them in order*" You were already correct when you said simultaneously vs in order (sequentially). Asynchronous and synchronous are both inappropriate terms here. You need a simultaneous sampling ADC. However, these are not inexpensive either and take even more work to put onto a PCB. Soil moisture levels change so slowly that electronic sequential sampling is probably fast enough it might as well be simultaneous.

Comment: Is it low power that you need? What do you mean by async? Any processor can poll sensors on any time interval

Comment: @DKNguyen Indeed, thanks for the clarification regarding Asynchronous and synchronous terms. It is neccesary that all the sensors read simultaneously because: the way we read the data makes it that every sensor takes 30 seconds to read the data (we take 10 readings with a space gap in between each), and as the system grows up, it will take ages to finish all the readings.

Comment: @Hearth ADCs just converts one signal into another. Now, 8 bit microcontrollers can only work with one instruction at the time. This is clearly inefficient for my needs. Not only do I need simultaneous readings for the sensors, but also for some calculations our systems make, datalog, and most important, when valve #1 is open, the system has to wait for it to close before it can continue with the next sensor.

Comment: @Julián Can you not sequentially interleave samples between sensors? What's happening in the 30 seconds you spend sampling one sensor?

Comment: @Julián All simple microprocessors work with only one instruction at a time. If you want more than that, you'll need a multi-core processor, which is a large step up in price and an even larger step up in programming complexity.

Comment: `every sensor takes 30 seconds to read the data` ... don't you mean `30 seconds to perform a measurement`? ... the data is probably transmitted very quickly ... why don't you start the measurement  and then come back 30 seconds later to retrieve the data? ... which sensor are you using

Comment: There is no question. If an AVR can't handle 10 sensors efficiently enough for you, why do you think the problem is the MCU, instead of the problem being in your code? Which sensors you have and how do you use them? Why measurements must be simultaneous, why it is not enough to e.g. read ten sensors in 10 seconds? Do you expect the moisture level to even change significantly in 10 seconds?

Comment: Tell about the sensors to sample beyond *10 capacitive sensors*. Don't hide information like `the way we read the data […] takes 30 seconds [per sensor]` in a comment: edit it into your question's body.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the approach to reading values from more than one sensor.

Taking multiple readings from a sensor is a time-proven approach to improve accuracy - going only so far.

But instead of

1. capture sensor *i*'s reading
2. done if *k* readings wait for processing
3. wait for one quantum
4. repeat from 1.

for each sensor *i* of *n*,

0. set up a "quantum" timer
1. on timer interrupt

   - capture each sensor's reading in turn
   - if *k* readings for each sensor wait for processing, do process